# Assigning attributes to factors with a list

Tags: r, list, attributes, data.table

I have a datatable as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
    "A   B   D  E  iso   year   
     1   A   1  NA ECU   2009   
     2   B   2  0  ECU   2009   
     3   D   3  0  BRA   2011   
     4   E   4  0  BRA   2011   
     5   D   7  NA ECU   2008   
     6   E   1  0  ECU   2008   
     7   A   3  2  BRA   2012   
     8   A   4  NA BRA   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
dt <- dt[, D := as.factor(D)]
```

I would like to assign attributes to column `D`. I tried the following:

```
alist <- list("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
attributes(dt$D) <- alist
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in attributes(dt$D) <- alist : attributes must be named
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
alist <- list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))
attributes(dt$D) <- setNames(alist, c("D"))
```

gives output as

```
> attributes(dt$D)
$D
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"
```

Comment: one liner 
`attributes(dt$D) <- list(D = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))` or use lst() instead like `attributes(dt$D) <- lst(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))`